# Pause crawler from its inception to some next datetime

Tags: scrapy

I want to pause all requests for some amount of seconds once my crawler reaches the 20 seconds of running beyond the current timer. Then have it continue as usual until complete.

I find that my current script does not implement the pause and the spider continues as usual, how do I make it work effectively?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
import datetime
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import defer
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'signal'

    start_urls = start_urls = [f'https://www.meadowhall.co.uk/eatdrinkshop?page={i}' for i in range(1, 15)]

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':2
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = 0
        self.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(TestSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.schedule_request, signal=signals.request_scheduled)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.close_spider, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider
    
    def schedule_request(self):
        self.timer += 1
        if self.datetime == (self.datetime + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 20)).time():
            deferred = defer.Deferred()
            deferred.pause(self.timer)
            deferred.unpause()
            
        
    def close_spider(self):
        print(f"The current time: {datetime.datetime.now().time()}")

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse,
                cb_kwargs = {
                    'pg':url
                }
            ) 
    def parse(self, response,pg):
        content_page = response.xpath("//div[@class='view-content']//div")
        url_split = pg.split('?')[-1]
        for cnt in content_page:
            image_url = cnt.xpath(".//img//@src").get()
            if image_url != None:
                yield {
                    'image_urls':image_url,
                    'url_page':url_split
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier than I thought, I was definitely over complicating the process. The scrapy document on [telnetconsole](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html#:%7E:text=Pause%2C%20resume%20and%20stop%20the%20Scrapy%20engine) gives the example of using `engine.pause`. Whilst `time.sleep` is not recommended within a scrapy crawler, because we are already pausing the process directly with scrapy's methods, then we just add a sleep until `engine.unpause` to start it again.

Therefore, something like this would work:

```
    end_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 3)
    def __init__(self, stats, pause):
       self.stats = stats
       self.pause = pause

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        #spider = super(TestSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        stat = cls(crawler.stats, crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(stat.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(stat.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return stat

    def spider_opened(self):
        
        start_time = self.stats.get_stats()['start_time']
        if datetime.datetime.now().time() >= (start_time+ self.end_time).time():
            print(f"The time final: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
            self.pause.engine.pause()
            time.sleep(5)
            self.pause.engine.unpause()
```

And so we can pause based on how long its been running for and when we want it to pause and for how long. There should be possibilities to include this within a loop, and so we can pause after every some amount of seconds, and if the scraping is done we break the loop and close the spider.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only pauses at the start. My guess is because I have opened the signal with `spider.opened`, an alternative option may be more appropriate. I will have to look into this and keep this post updated.

Comment: This wont work because we cannot use `time.sleep` to pause the coroutines. I'll have to develop a pause based on methods provided by twisted.